# DataSnap REST Server Client's timeout issue - Berlin

Tags: delphi, datasnap, request-timed-out

I am in some strange situation. I made DataSnap REST server and client. All REST server's methods are call by client through TRESTClient. My REST Server is Apache Module. Also I used TSQLConnection & TDSClientCallbackChannelManager for Peer-to-Peer callback in cleint. I set TDSServer ChannelResponseTimeout = 0 and TDSHTTPWebDispatcher SessionTimeout = 0. Still my client timed out after few seconds. I set TDSClientCallbackChannelManager CommunicationTimeout=0 and ConnectionTimeout=0. The error I am getting in TWinHTTPClient.DoExecuteRequest method of System.Net.HttpClient.Win. Strange thing is on debug mode I got AV but in exe mode I don't receive any AV but none of my callback is working though the REST methods are executing. I also tried set LifeCyle of TDSServerClass to Session & Invocation, both gives timed out. Below is some code for DSClientCallback & TSQLConnection:

```
SQLConnection.Params.Values['HostName'] := SERVERIP;
SQLConnection.Params.Values['Port'] := SERVER_PORT.ToString;
SQLConnection.Params.Values['ConnectionTimeout'] := '0';
SQLConnection.Connected := True;

ClientCallbackManager.CommunicationTimeout := '0';
ClientCallbackManager.ConnectionTimeout := '0';
ClientCallbackManager.DSHostname := SERVERIP;
ClientCallbackManager.DSPort := SERVER_PORT.ToString;
fClientCallbackId := TDSTunnelSession.GenerateSessionId;
ClientCallbackManager.DSPath := 'mypath';
ClientCallbackManager.ManagerId := TDSTunnelSession.GenerateSessionId;
fClientId := ClientCallbackManager.ManagerId;
ClientCallbackManager.RegisterCallback(fClientCallbackId,
'mychannel', TServerCallback.Create);
```

What I am doing wrong or missing? Please help. I also post this to Embarcadero Datasnap Forum without any response https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=229678&tstart=0

Comment: I found the problem, it's in TDSClientCallbackChannelManager which cause The Operation timed out. How to resolve it?

Comment: Hello, @shariful. Did you solve the problem?